# What is A, T, T in this macro function?

Tags: assembly, macros, arm

```
.macro  add_sh          rd,  rn,  rm,  sh:vararg
A       add             \rd, \rn, \rm, \sh
T       mov             \rm, \rm, \sh
T       add             \rd, \rn, \rm
.endm
```

What is A, T, T in this macro function?

What is the need for using these? What they meant exactly?

I hope somebody will help me regarding this.

Comment: What CPU family and what assembler ? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that this is ARM assembly code and the `A` and `T` macros are used to select which instructions to assemble depending on whether you are building (A)RM code or (T)humb code:

```
.macro  add_sh          rd,  rn,  rm,  sh:vararg
A       add             \rd, \rn, \rm, \sh          ;; ARM - just one instruction
T       mov             \rm, \rm, \sh               ;; Thumb - these two instructions
T       add             \rd, \rn, \rm               ;;         ...
.endm
```

Comment: I think you might be right. This is syntax I've never seen before. In ARM UAL, you should just be able to use the `add rd, rn, op2` format and it should compile appropriately for ARM or Thumb (though it might generate the two instructions for Thumb. The quick reference doesn't note it as unavailable in Thumb, but it does say that it may be 32-bits wide in Thumb-2.